# jquery mobile tap event

Tags: jquery, events, mobile, jquery-mobile

```
$(function() {
    $('.quickNav').live('tap',function(event) {
        if ($(".select_body").is(":hidden")) 
        {
                $(".select_body").show(); 
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(".select_body").hide(); 
        }        
    });
});
```

This works fine except for once it is visible and you tap again it doesn't go away.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 15):

```
$('.quickNav').live('tap',function(event) {
    $(".select_body").toggle(); //  toggles the visibility/display of the element.
});
```

this does the same as the lengthy if/else script

See [toggle method documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) in the jQuery API docs.

Answer (score 0):

Once the element is hidden, its height and width are zero. This means when you tap the same place, you don't actually hit the element a second time.

I would recommend setting its opacity to zero instead.
Here's kind of what you could do:

```
$(function() {
    $('.quickNav').live('tap',function(event) {
        if ($(".select_body").is(":hidden"))
        {
            $(".select_body").css("opacity", 1);
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(".select_body").css("opacity", 0);
        }        
    });
});
```

and a shorter version of the same behaviour:

```
$(function() {
    $('.quickNav').live('tap',function(event) {
        $(".select_body").css("opacity", 1 - parseInt($(".select_body").css("opacity")));
    });
});
```

I havent actually tested this code, so I don't even know if it will run!

note: fadeOut() will use hide() at the end of its animation, so it doesn't really help here.